# Why is R self-reported memory usage much inferior to MAC-reported memory usage?

Tags: r, macos, memory

I am facing a memory issue with an R script of mine that I cannot understand. In short, the script takes as input a list of paths to data tables and the script builds one big data table (about 10k rows and 2k columns) by aggregating iteratively each input table.

I tried to run locally on my MAC OS (Mojave, Memory: 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3) but I run out of memory before the script ends. However, the complete aggregated table should not exceed 500Mb and I don't have many intermediate variables that would make the memory full.

I used `pryr` and `profvis` R packages to profile the memory usage alone the script. Here is some of the output

```
-INFO MEMORY: total memory usage is 223.99 MB
-INFO: adding DNA Mutation counts per pathway from table count_by_pathway_cpad_kegg_DNA_non_synonymous_tcga. tsv (8974,42) ... done!
-INFO: adding DNA Mutation counts per pathway from table count_by_pathway_sanchez_vega_DNA_non_synonymous_tcga.tsv (8974,12) ... done!
-INFO: adding DNA Mutation counts per pathway from table count_by_pathway_msigdb_hallmarks_DNA_non_synonymous_tcga.tsv (8974,52) ... done!
-INFO MEMORY: size of dfs is 81.79 MB
-INFO MEMORY: total memory usage is 253.44 MB
-INFO: adding MUT counts total from table count_total_DNA_all_tcga.tsv (8974,3) ... done!
-INFO MEMORY: size of dfs is 81.97 MB
-INFO MEMORY: total memory usage is 260.74 MB
-INFO: adding DNA Alteration counts per gene from table count_by_gene_DNA_annotated_tcga.tsv (3630,373) ... done!
-INFO MEMORY: size of dfs is 130.17 MB
-INFO MEMORY: total memory usage is 322.26 MB
-INFO: adding DNA Alteration counts per pathway from table count_by_pathway_cpad_kegg_DNA_annotated_tcga.tsv (3630,123) ... done!
-INFO: adding DNA Alteration counts per pathway from table count_by_pathway_sanchez_vega_DNA_annotated_tcga.tsv (3630,24) ... done!
-INFO: adding DNA Alteration counts per pathway from table count_by_pathway_msigdb_hallmarks_DNA_annotated_tcga.tsv (3630,137) ... done!
-INFO MEMORY: size of dfs is 166.64 MB
-INFO MEMORY: total memory usage is 400.82 MB
```

Here is the code for the last function I called

```
dfs <- add_counts(args$dna_alt_counts_pathway, dfs, agg="pathway", evt_type="Alteration", data_type="DNA", cohort=args$cohort)

add_counts <- function(filepaths, dfs, agg="gene", data_type="DNA", evt_type="Alteration", cohort="prism"){
  dfs_data <- lapply(filepaths, load_table)
  if (length(dfs_data)==0) return(dfs)

  if (agg %in% c("pathway")){
    pattern_1 <- paste0("(?<=count_by_", agg, "_)[a-z0-9A-Z\\_\\-]+(?=_", data_type, ")")
    level_names_1 <- sapply(filepaths, function(s) str_extract(s, pattern_1), USE.NAMES=F)
  } else {
    level_names_1 <- agg
  }

  pattern_2 <- paste0("(?<=_", data_type, "_)[a-z0-9A-Z\\_\\-]+(?=_", cohort, ")")
  level_names_2 <- sapply(filepaths, function(s) str_extract(s, pattern_2), USE.NAMES=F)

  col_tsb <- "Tumor_Sample_Barcode"
  col_nsb <- "Matched_Norm_Sample_Barcode"
  col_psb <- "Sample_Id_DNA_P"

  for (i in 1:length(filepaths)){
    df_dat_cnt <- dfs_data[[i]]
    level_1 <- level_names_1[[i]]
    level_2 <- level_names_2[[i]]
    
    dat_size <- paste0("(", nrow(df_dat_cnt), ",", ncol(df_dat_cnt), ")")
    cat(paste("-INFO: adding", data_type, evt_type, "counts per", agg, "from table", basename(filepaths[[i]]), 
              dat_size, "..."))

    if (all(c(col_tsb, col_nsb) %in% colnames(df_dat_cnt))){
      df_dat_cnt <- df_dat_cnt %>% unite(!!col_psb, all_of(c(col_tsb, col_nsb)), sep="_vs_")
    }

    col_row <- intersect(c(col_psb, "Tumor_Sample_Barcode", "Sample_Id", "Subject_Id"), colnames(df_dat_cnt))[1]
    df_dat_cnt <- df_dat_cnt %>% column_to_rownames(var=col_row)
    df_dat_sts <- df_dat_cnt %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) as.integer(as.logical(x))) 

    plot_names <- colnames(df_dat_cnt)
    colnames(df_dat_cnt) <- paste0(colnames(df_dat_cnt), "_", data_type, "_count_", level_2)
    colnames(df_dat_sts) <- paste0(colnames(df_dat_sts), "_", data_type, "_status_", level_2)

    df_cov_cnt <- data.frame(Covariate=colnames(df_dat_cnt), Plot_Name=plot_names) %>% 
      mutate(Nature="Continuous", Class_Lvl_1=data_type,
             Class_Lvl_2=paste0(evt_type, "_Counts_", str_to_title(agg)), 
             Class_Lvl_3=paste0(level_1, "_", level_2))

    df_cov_sts <- data.frame(Covariate=colnames(df_dat_sts), Plot_Name=plot_names) %>% 
      mutate(Nature="Binary", Class_Lvl_1=data_type,
             Class_Lvl_2=paste0(evt_type, "_Status_", str_to_title(agg)), 
             Class_Lvl_3=paste0(level_1, "_", level_2))

    if (col_row!="Subject_Id" & col_row!=col_psb){
      if (data_type=="RNA"){
        col_row <- "Sample_Id_RNA_T"
      } else {
        col_row <- "Sample_Id_DNA_T"
      }
    }

    df_dat_cnt <- df_dat_cnt %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column(var=col_row)
    df_dat_sts <- df_dat_sts %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column(var=col_row)

    dfs$dat <- left_join(dfs$dat, df_dat_cnt, by=col_row)
    dfs$cov <- bind_rows(dfs$cov, df_cov_cnt)
    
    if (!agg %in% c("total")){
      dfs$dat <- left_join(dfs$dat, df_dat_sts, by=col_row)
      dfs$cov <- bind_rows(dfs$cov, df_cov_sts)
    }

    cat(" done!\n")
  }

  print_size_object(dfs)
  print_total_memory()
  dfs
}

print_size_object <- function(obj){
  obj_name <- deparse(substitute(obj))
  obj_size <- object_size(obj)
  if (obj_size > 1e9){
    print_size <- round(obj_size/1e9, 2)
    unit_size <- "GB"
  } else {
    print_size <- round(obj_size/1e6, 2)
    unit_size <- "MB"
  }
  cat(paste("-INFO MEMORY: size of", obj_name, "is", print_size, unit_size, "\n"))
}

print_total_memory <- function(){
  mem_size <- mem_used()
  if (mem_size > 1e9){
    print_size <- round(mem_size/1e9, 2)
    unit_size <- "GB"
  } else {
    print_size <- round(mem_size/1e6, 2)
    unit_size <- "MB"
  }
  cat(paste("-INFO MEMORY: total memory usage is", print_size, unit_size, "\n"))
}
```

After running this line, the activity monitor reports the following statistics for the R process running

[image: R_process]

However, running `mem_used` from R console returns

```
266 MB
```

What is the reason for having a RSS > 3Gb when R objects occupy 266 Mb? And why is VMZ so huge? During the execution of

```
dfs <- add_counts(args$dna_alt_counts_pathway, dfs, agg="pathway", evt_type="Alteration", data_type="DNA", cohort=args$cohort)
```

the VMZ increased from about 10Gb to >30Gb and it does not seem to decrease a lot after the execution is finished.

Thank you very much for your help, I can't get my head around this issue!

Best,
Yoann

Comment: If you run into memory issues, switching to data.table, or dtplyr and data.table to keep dplyr syntax, might help.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi thank you for your quick answers. The function `mem_used()` is supposed to capture all objects existing in the R session and this function reports 266 Mb. I checked manually by listing all objects in the R session through `ls` and summing the size of each object using `object_size()`, the total was very close to what is reported `mem_used()`.

Comment: @phiver thank you for your suggestions. I already use `dplyr` along with `readr` and `readxl` for reading tables which I believe are quite optimized. I find it hard to believe that changing `data.table` will drastically reduce the memory usage. To be honest, i tried running the code on a cluster with 1.5 Tb of RAM available and it also ran out of memory in the end. I feel like something is wrong in the code but I can't understand what.

Comment: @Durzot, data.table mutates variables by reference and doesn't copy the complete data.frame. Which dplyr still does, as far as I'm aware. And yes you are looping and building increasing the data.frame size. That tends to run in memory issues as the data.frame R doesn't know the size of the data.frame and when adding to it, it uses a lot of memory. Without having sample data to see how your process is working exactly it is difficult to say where improvements can be made. But the loop is probably the biggest hurdle.

Comment: @phiver, I continued investigating and based on your suggestions incriminating libraries, I used some old conda environments I created 1 year ago. I am pleased to say that all memory issues vanish when using this 1-year old environment. It means that some newer version of one or more of the libraries I use causes all this fuss. I am going to continue investigating to identify the culprit...